# Set GCC as Clion C++ compiler

Tags: gcc, c++, clion

I'm trying to set GCC as Clion c++ compiler from settings, but I found many gcc files like : gcc, gcc-8, gcc-ar, gcc-nm, and I don't know which one to attach in c++ compiler in Toolchain.
I'm totally new to Ubuntu and Clion also.

Comment: Attach gcc or gcc-8 in C++ compiler in toolchain. gcc-8 is the latest installed version which is a good choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach gcc or gcc-8 in C++ compiler in toolchain. gcc-8 is the latest installed version which is a good choice.